# How to get max value of a column in where clause in EF Core

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I have many sheets which have different version. I want to get the latest version of a sheet. like this in SQL:

```
SELECT Id, SheetId, Version, Title, CreatedTime 
FROM Sheets 
WHERE SheetId = 10 
  AND Version = (SELECT MAX(Version) WHERE SheetId = 10)
```

How could I get the latest version of the sheet in EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Sheets.Where(x => x.SheetId == 10 && x.Version ==
    db.Sheets.Where(x => x.SheetId == 10).Select(x => x.Version).Max())
```

It should work.